# Seeking shapefile of urban, suburban, and rural areas of US

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, census

[image]

I'm looking for something like this, doesn't have to be super accurate. I've tried searching for the source of that image but to no avail.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: FYI Natural Earth has Urban Polygons at 1:10m https://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/

Comment: Your Image is from the National Center for Education Statistics https://nces.ed.gov/pubs2007/ruraled/exhibit_c.asp (a high res pdf is available to download)